# Configurable Products All simple products not listing in associated product options - Magento

Tags: php, magento

Friends want help. There are 73814 simple products in total but on Configurable Products only showing 73604 products guys. Any help would be appreciated

[Simple Products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjZL3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Simple Products will not list in associated product options, If selected super attribute value is not assigned in those products. Please check to export simple products that all have values assigned for super attribute or not.